# code . command working in VSCode Terminal, but not on Windows Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

System Specs:

- Windows 10
- WSL
- Windows Terminal
- VSCode

Everytime I try to run `code .`, [zsh states that the command isn't found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ6Cb.png).

When I try it on VSCode though, VSCode opens up without any problem.

A similar problem happens when I try to open `.zshrc`, to which it works flawlessly on VSCode, but on Windows Terminal, it states that I did not have permission to access that file.

[My path looks good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B62d.png)

Comment: Invoke the command by explicitly stating the absolute path, or put its directory into `PATH`. BTW, what does it say when you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`?

Comment: It gives me 5.8.

Comment: UPDATE: I found a fix for this.

In the end, all I had to do was paste the path directly into my `./zshrc` as such:
`alias code='/mnt/c/Users/fl1p_/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code'`

Comment: Of course, as with **every** command, you can always choose to provide the absolute path explicitly or use `PATH`  to search. BTW: The path you linked in your quesiion, does not look good, It contains backslashes.